# How do I give a method to an object that is defined inside of a click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

So what I want to make a method for txt, but I don't know how. I remember that it was something with "=>" operator but I can't remember the correct syntax. Can someone help me? This is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ex_y += 25;
            n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                this.Controls.Add(b);
                b.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                b.Location = new Point(ex_x + b.Width + 25, ex_y);
                ex_x = b.Location.X;
                b.Text = rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
                a[i] = int.Parse(b.Text);

                rand.Next(0, 100);
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                this.Controls.Add(txt);
                txt.Size = new Size(b.Size.Width, 50);
                txt.Location = new Point(b.Location.X, b.Location.Y + 60);
                txt.BackColor = Color.White;    

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you want to subscribe to the event, that is done with the `+=` operator. Here is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events).

For example:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Click += new System.EventHandler(b_Click);
    this.Controls.Add(b);
    b.Size = new Size(50, 50);
}

private void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I was clicked!");
}
```